# Generating a new id or number with while, do or for loop

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, while-loop, slider

first of all I apologize for my bad english skill

I have a dynamic slider for my ecommarce. but  I have a problem with links titles. I need to generate numbers ord new ids from 1 to 9 and put them as images' numbers or new ids.

Here is my code.

```
 $sqlslide= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_add DESC LIMIT 9");
    $count2 = mysql_num_rows($sqlslide);
    if($count2 > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlslid)){
                $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $source = "products/$id.jpg";
            $img = '<img src="'.$source.'" class="photo" alt="temp">';
            $slide1 .=' <div class="panel" title="'.$id.'">
             <div class="wrapper">
             '.$img.'
            <div class="photo-meta-data">
            '.$name.$id.' <br />
             "'.$descriotion.'
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                ';
            $img2 = '<img src="'.$source.'" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb">';
            $nav_thumb .='
            <div><a href="'.$id.'" class="cross-link">'.$img2.$id.'</a></div>
            '
            ;
    }
```

I need to replace  `'.$id.'` in title  and the link with new generated numbers or ids in

```
 $slide1 .=' <div class="panel" title="'.$id.'">
<a href="'.$id.'" class="cross-link">'.$img2.'</a>
```

so question is, how can I generate with while, do or for loop new numbers or ids for them and replace the `'.$id.'` with it?

thanx

Comment: Use a separate `counter` flag.

Comment: how, I have no idea how to use it, Iäm just a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqlslide= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_add DESC LIMIT 9");
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($sqlslide);
if($count2 > 0){
    $index=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlslid)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $source = "products/$id.jpg";
        $img = '<img src="'.$source.'" class="photo" alt="temp">';
        $slide1 .=' <div class="panel" title="'.$index.'">
         <div class="wrapper">
         '.$img.'
        <div class="photo-meta-data">
        '.$name.$id.' <br />
         "'.$descriotion.'
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            ';
        $img2 = '<img src="'.$source.'" class="nav-thumb" alt="temp-thumb">';
        $nav_thumb .='
        <div><a href="'.$index.'" class="cross-link">'.$img2.$id.'</a></div>
        '
        ...
        $index++;
        } // end while
}
```

Edit 1:

The concept of generating incremented numbers:

```
 $index=0;
 while($index<9) // incremented numbers till 9
 {
   echo $index;
   $index++;
 }
```

Comment: thank all of you guys it gave this erro:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$index' (T_VARIABLE) at on line 61 where $index++;

Comment: @KimF Put `$index=0;` before your loop starts, and `$index++`; before ur `while` ends.

Comment: I have put them in that order that you say, but still I get that error :(

Comment: @KimF Then check for the misplace `'` and `"` in your code. That may be the reason.

Comment: A ; was missed but now it gives this error:

 mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.elcrto.com\index.php on line 38  where is  

 $count2 = mysql_num_rows($sqlslide);

Comment: @KimF Provide the db connection variable in mysql query statement. e.g: `mysql_query($sql,$con);` where `$con` is my connection variable.

Comment: thank you, now it generates the numbers, but when I click on small images it doent show the big images in slider ?

Comment: by clicking on the right mark? if so, I did :)
thanx again

Answer (score 0):

i understand you right?

```
$no = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlslid))
{

    //do something.
    $no++;
    if($no > 9)
    {
      $no = 1;
    }
}
```